# rhash -M argument not working in zsh on macOS

Tags: linux, macos, sh, zsh

I need to have the equivalent command of `rhash -M Filename.jpg` in macOS zshell. The above command works in ubuntu 16.04 but if i try the same command in zsh. It gives me error `zsh: command not found: rhash`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with `rhash`, but it seems to generate an MD5 sum, so on a Mac, you can do:

```
md5 -q SomeFile
7df25d6181c015d4cf3e003d5d84a0d9
```

If that is not perfect, run `man md5` to find alternative output formats.

---

If you have **hombebrew**, you can also install `rhash` with:

```
brew install rhash
```